# How to get corresponding heading to paragraph text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to get the all the text and associate it with the corresponding header.

For example, suppose the following Word document

```
HEADING 1
text one
text two
SUBHEADING 1.1
text three
text four
text five
SUBHEADING 1.1.1
text six
text seven
text eight
HEADING 2
text nine
HEADING 2.1
text ten
...
```

I have already been able to get the text by creating one really long string with a ',' as the delimiter to then be converted to an array.
So as the program is going through to get all the text I want to get the last numbered heading/subheading so then it can be associated as so:

```
[, text one, text two, text three]
[, 1       , 1,      , 1.1       ]
```

It should be noted that I only want headings/subheadings with numbers (i.e., list format), so something like "Section 1" would not be a heading I would want. However, if it were simply "1" then I want it in the list.

I've tried using `OutlineLevel`, but it gives me all the headings at once (I need it as it's going through).
I've also tried using the `Like` operator, but the headings do not appear when getting the text because I get it as `paragraph.Range.Text`. In other words, headings are not classified the as text.

The following is what I currently have

```
Dim doc As Document
Dim para As Paragraph
Dim lastNumericHeading As String
Dim textWithHeading As String

Dim finalText As String
Dim finalHeadings As String

Dim textArr() As String 
Dim headingsArr() As String

Dim isNumberedHeading As Boolean

Set doc = ActiveDocument
textWithHeading = ""
lastNumericHeading = ""
finalText = ""
finalHeadings = ""

' GET ALL TEXT AND HEADINGS
For Each para in Doc.Paragraphs
    isNumberedHeading = helperFunction() ' use arguments as needed
    If isNumberedHeading Then
        ' TODO: set lastNumericHeading
    Else
        finalText = finalText & "," & para.Range.Text
        finalHeadings = finalHeadings & "," & lastNumericHeading
    End If
Next Para

' CONVERT TO ARRAY
textArr = Split(finalText, ",")
headingArr = Split(finalHeadings, ",")

' PRINT TEXT WITH ASSOCIATED HEADING
For i = LBound(textArr) To UBound(textArr)
    Debug.Print headingArr(i)
    Debug.Print textArr(i)
Next i
```

Helper function:

```
Function helperFunction() As Boolean' use arguments as needed
    ' TODO if required
End Function
```

EDIT:
the following code also worked for me, although @taller 's answer also worked as well.

```
Sub ExtractTextWithHeadings()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim lastNumericHeading As String
    Dim textWithHeading As String

    Dim finalText As String
    Dim finalHeadings As String

    Dim textArr() As String
    Dim headingArr() As String

    Dim isNumberedHeading As Boolean

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    textWithHeading = ""
    lastNumericHeading = ""
    finalText = ""
    finalHeadings = ""

    ' GET ALL TEXT AND HEADINGS
    For Each para In doc.Paragraphs
        isNumberedHeading = IsNumberedHeading(para)
        If isNumberedHeading Then
            lastNumericHeading = para.Range.ListFormat.ListString
        Else
            finalText = finalText & "," & para.Range.Text
            finalHeadings = finalHeadings & "," & lastNumericHeading
        End If
    Next para

    ' CONVERT TO ARRAY
    textArr = Split(finalText, ",")
    headingArr = Split(finalHeadings, ",")

    ' PRINT TEXT WITH ASSOCIATED HEADING
    For i = LBound(textArr) To UBound(textArr)
        Debug.Print headingArr(i)
        Debug.Print textArr(i)
    Next i
End Sub

Function IsNumberedHeading(para As Paragraph) As Boolean
    ' Check if the paragraph is a numbered heading based on outline level
    Dim outlineLevel As Integer
    outlineLevel = para.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber
    
    ' Check if the paragraph is a numbered heading (outline level > 1)
    IsNumberedHeading = (outlineLevel > 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of `heading`. Is it a style or multilevel list?

Comment: @taller it's a style, but the numbers are a multilevel list

Comment: In your question, you use the term "header." There is a huge difference in Word between a "header" and a "heading." https://addbalance.com/word/headersheadings.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The names of heading style are `Heading 1`, `Heading 2`, `Heading 3` in testing doc. If you are using different names, please modify `helperFunction` as needed.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim lastNumericHeading As String
    Dim textWithHeading As String
    Dim finalText As String
    Dim finalHeadings As String
    Dim textArr As Variant
    Dim headingsArr As Variant
    Dim isNumberedHeading As Boolean
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    textWithHeading = ""
    lastNumericHeading = ""
    finalText = ""
    finalHeadings = ""
    ' GET ALL TEXT AND HEADINGS
    For Each para In doc.Paragraphs
        isNumberedHeading = helperFunction(para) ' use arguments as needed
        If isNumberedHeading Then
            lastNumericHeading = para.Range.ListFormat.ListString
        Else
            finalText = finalText & "," & para.Range.Text
            finalHeadings = finalHeadings & "," & lastNumericHeading
        End If
    Next para
    ' CONVERT TO ARRAY
    textArr = Split(Mid(finalText,2), ",")
    headingsArr = Split(Mid(finalHeadings,2), ",")
    Dim i As Long
    ' PRINT TEXT WITH ASSOCIATED HEADING
    For i = LBound(textArr) To UBound(textArr)
        Debug.Print headingsArr(i), textArr(i)
    Next i
End Sub
Function helperFunction(oPara As Paragraph) As Boolean ' use arguments as needed
    helperFunction = False
    If Left(oPara.Style, 7) = "Heading" Then
        Dim sListStr As String
        sListStr = oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListString
        If Len(sListStr) > 0 Then
            If IsNumeric(Replace(sListStr, ".", "")) Then
                helperFunction = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Testing document:

[image]

Output:

```
1.            Text 1
1.            Text 2
1.1.          Text 3
1.1.          Text 4
1.1.1.        Text 5
1.1.1.        Text 6
2.            Text 7
2.            Text 8
2.1.          Text 9
2.1.          Text 10
```